# Adding a key from a variable string (es6) when using spread syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

I would like to know if there is a clean way to set the value of a key from a string variable when using spread syntax in es6?

Something like the following:

```
let keyVar = 'newKey'
let newObject = {keyVar:{some:'json'},...oldObject}
```

But this leads to:

`{"keyVar":{"some":"json"}, ... }`

rather than:

`{"newKey":{"some":"json"}, ... }`

Comment: FYI, "spread properties" are not part of ES6. They are currently a proposal, i.e. an experimental feature. But it doesn't change how to set the property anyway. It also has nothing to do with JSON.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use [computed properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```js
const keyVar = 'newKey';
const newObject = { [keyVar]: { some: 'json' } };
console.log(newObject);
```